# On Linear spaces: is the product of a scalar by a linear combination equal the l.c of same vectors with each scarlar multiplied by the first one?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If E is a vectorial space over a field K, we know that if $t \in K$ and if $a \in E$ and $b \in E$ then $t(a + b)= ta + tb$, by induction we can carry it out to countable subsets of E.

But dealing with $S(X)$ - the span of some non empty subset $X$ of $E$ we may be interested in some linear combinations that are not countably, such as when we study $S(E)$ or the set of all linear combination of some different uncountable subset of E.

Thereby what is possibly to do? Is really $t(\sum_{i \in X} c_i x_i ) = \sum_{i \in X} t c_i x_i $ even X being uncountable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear combination is always finite.

Note that your induction argument will actually say that for any finite set of vectors $a_1,\dots,a_n\in E$ and a scalar $t\in K$, you get $t(a_1+\dots+a_n)=ta_1+\dots+ta_n$, but it says nothing about the limit case. In fact the limit case need not even make any sense in terms of the vector space! For instance $1+1+1+\dots$ is not an element of $\mathbb{R}$.

The span of any subset $X\subset E$, even for uncountable $X$, is just by definition all the finite (but arbitrarily large) linear combinations
$$S(X) = \{c_1x_1+\dots+c_nx_n:\; n\in\mathbb{N}, c_1,\dots,c_n\in K, x_1,\dots,x_n\in X \},$$
so there is no need for any notion of uncountable linear combination here.